# Is it feasible to show whole path of ECL asset in CME?

Tags: content-manager, ecl

In our project We have integrated the ECL to the CME. Now we have came across one requirement to show the whole path of asset in the ECL to CME while selecting it from ECL DAM. Currently whenever you select the external asset from DAM,it only insert the file name of the asset in the field of CME. the problem with this sceario is that  author does not know from which folder he has inserted the asset from external DAM.

Please let me know whether its feasible to do that with ECL.

Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible simply having your ECL provider report the full path as the title of the asset. As the title is not stored anywhere in Tridion (except as a default value in for example rich text fields as far as I remember), you should not directly run into the length restriction applied to the title of Tridion items. You can exceed the length CME has been designed to work with though, so I imagine it could look a bit strange here and there.

In case your real requirement is "it should be possible to easily find out what the path is" as opposed to "It must be visible right on the same window" then simply opening the item (I believe this is available from the CME directly by clicking the thumbnail or something like that) will show the item. You can then add the path to the External Metadata. It will be a few clicks and seconds away, but that might be good enough for some requirements.